# how is task Scheduled(allocated) to CPU using Shortest job first method?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

I have some clear understanding about Time slicing algorithm for CPU task scheduling.But i have some confusion with Shortest job first algorithm.

For example:

I have two programs.

one program with infinite loop and another with finite loop.In this situation,how CPU determining job for execute by using shortest job first.

CPU only understand this kind of situation while executing those programs(Whether it is infinite or finite).

Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Thanks & Regards,
Saravanan.P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taking the Job with the [lowest process burst assumption](http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/oskomp/vt07/lectures/scheduling_algorithms/handout.pdf) (intervals with no I/O-Usage). Computers can't really determine infinite loops or tell if it's just a long query, but it can determine I/O-usage.